# How to say "in solid rock" in Latin to convey specific technical meaning?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, word-choice

I am writing a paper that describes nuclear reactions that take place in the earth's crust leading to the formation of volatile gases. In several places, I need to distinguish between things that happen in solid rock vs in microscopic gas pockets that can form in pores and between grain boundaries. I would like to introduce a technical term to denote the former since I find myself repeating the verbose distinction several times.

How best to render "in rock" in Latin? My dictionary suggests *"in saxo"* and *"in scopulo"*, but those both seem to suggest a rocky outcropping or a piece of rock, and I'm hoping to convey something more like "in solid bedrock". *"In silico"* would probably work, except that it already has a very different technical meaning in this field (referring to simulations "on silicon" as opposed to experiment).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Interesting question. I wonder if _terra_ could work here, even though it's not specifically about rock.

Comment: *terra*'s not a bad choice. Without any context I would probably read *in terra* as "underground, but that's less relevant since I am defining the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*petra* is the word sometimes used for the material of rock, also *lapis*

In Pliny at one point it reads:

*Sunt in Bononiensi Italiae parte breves maculae complexu silicis alligatae*

(In the region of Bologna in Italy small streaks occur tightly embedded within hard rock...)

The inner part of the earth is called the *viscera* and in mining the mother rock is referred to as the *viscera montium*.

In *De Re Metallica* and other books on mining, the authors frequently speak of *commissurae saxorum* (seams of the rocks).

Comment: all good suggestions! I like *petra* since most educated readers could guess at the meaning even without context

Comment: from your last edit I think I'll go with *saxum* even though I initially rejected it since there is clear usage in exactly the connotation I need